# ggplot y axis - mutating count to percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a beginner at R and am having trouble making a plot that shows different responses (male vs female) as to how they rate their health status("Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent"). 
The problem is that there are more females than male respondents, so I made a little function to try to mutate the y-axis from count to percentages. Can someone please help? Here is the code:

```
brfss2013 %>% 
filter(!is.na(sex))%>%
count(sex) %>% 
mutate(perc = n / nrow(brfss2013)) -> brfss2

brfss2013%>%
filter(!is.na(sex))%>% 
filter(!is.na(genhlth))%>% 
group_by(sex, genhlth)%>%  
ggplot(brfss2013, mapping = aes(x = genhlth) + geom_bar(aes(fill = brfss2$sex),position = 
"dodge") + scale_fill_brewer("Gender") + labs(title = "Reported generalhealth - by gender", x = 
"general health - reported")
```

Comment: Hi - can you please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Its extremely difficult for us to help you without being able to run your code

Comment: Hi Conor, So, I still can't make one, as I am really, really new - 4 weeks ago I couldn't even run simple commands in RStudio. The data has 330 columns and 490,000 lines, so I don't know how representative a random sample would really be, anyway.

Comment: Hi Conor, So, I still can't make one, as I am really, really new - 4 weeks ago I couldn't even run simple commands in RStudio. The data has 330 columns and 490,000 lines, so I don't know how representative a random sample would really be, anyway. Just one question: the first function brfss2$perc
[1] 0.4093600 0.5906258, we see that 40.93% of respondents are male and 59.06% are female. So is it possible to create a line of code to sample randomly only 69.3% of females, so to roughly equal female and male respondents? Would it be a valid solution?

Answer (score 1):

@Tania - welcome to SO!

It is not entirely clear what your final desired plot should look like. But here is one potential way to pursue this. This example is based on BRFSS 2018 data.

First, it appears you would like to remove rows with `NA`.

Second, you can filter on those that have the expected `SEX1` and `GENHLTH` values, to exclude those that answered "not sure" or "refused."

Next, you can `group_by` both columns, and compute the percentages. Note the order in your `group_by` matters, it will give different results. By the grouping here, I wanted % to add up to 100 across `GENHLTH` (for each sex).

Finally, you can plot using the percentage as the vertical axis.

```
library(tidyverse)

BRFSS_b %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  filter(SEX1 == 1 | SEX1 == 2,
         GENHLTH >= 1 & GENHLTH <=5) %>%
  group_by(SEX1, GENHLTH) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(perc = n*100 / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = factor(GENHLTH), y = perc, fill = factor(SEX1))) + 
           geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
           scale_fill_brewer("Gender") + 
           labs(title = "Reported generalhealth - by gender", x = "general health - reported", y = "percent")
```

**Output**

[image: plot of percentage vs gen health by sex]

The data generated for `ggplot` looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   SEX1 [2]
    SEX1 GENHLTH     n  perc
   <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1     1       1 33272 16.9 
 2     1       2 63670 32.3 
 3     1       3 63411 32.2 
 4     1       4 26554 13.5 
 5     1       5  9962  5.06
 6     2       1 38454 16.1 
 7     2       2 78260 32.8 
 8     2       3 74531 31.3 
 9     2       4 34053 14.3 
10     2       5 13057  5.48
```

**Edit 3/23/20**:

If you want to plot "counts" instead of percent, you can do the following for `ggplot`. You probably need to add to `geom_bar` `stat="identity"` and make sure your variables are factors (if not already converted).

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = factor(GENHLTH), y = factor(n))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = factor(SEX1)), position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer("Gender") + 
  labs(title = "General health by gender", x = "reported general health")
```

Comment: your solution is great and the data preparation worked perfectly for me. However, I couldn't run it as a one-piece code, so created a new function - brfss3 (brfss3 <- brfss2013%>% filter(!is.na(sex))%>% filter(!is.na(genhlth))%>% group_by(sex, genhlth)%>%summarise(n = n())%>%mutate(perc = n*100 / sum(n)).

Comment: this gives the right percentages for each gender answer. But when I try to run in ggplot (ggplot(brfss3, mapping = aes(x = genhlth, y = n)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = (sex)), position = "dodge") + scale_fill_brewer("Gender") + labs(title = "General health by gender", x = "reported general health"), it returns the following error: Erro: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic

Comment: tried ggplot(data = brfss3, mapping = aes(x = genhlth, y = n )) + geom_bar(fill(brfss2013$sex),  position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + scale_fill_brewer("Gender") + labs(title = "Reported generalhealth - by gender", x = "general health - reported", y = "percentage") and got the folllowing error:
Error in UseMethod("fill_") : 
  method not applied to 'fill_' aplied to class "factor"

Comment: which makes no sense, because sex is of class factor

Comment: ben, now I finally made it. I tabled all the data and then got the maps right. Thank you so much!